# Initializate variables in abstract constructor class

Tags: java, variables, abstract-class

i have a abstractclass "HotelReviewClass" & "RestaurantReviewClass" where i want to initializate the variables which are not commun and commun go to "super" class

BUT i have a error "constructor call must be the first statement in a constructor"
How i can initilizate that uncommun variables ( because "HotelReviewClass" & "RestaurantReviewClass" variables are not equal)

```
package pt;

public class HotelReviewClass extends AbstractReview{

    private String ratingService;
    private String ratingLocal;

    public HotelReviewClass(String grade, String comment, String service, String local, String owner){
        this.ratingService = service;
        this.ratingLocal = local;
        super(grade, comment, owner);
    }

}
```

Comment: As it says, `super(...)` must go first.  Why don't you put it first?

Comment: because if i put first the code:

this.ratingService = service;
this.ratingLocal = local;

is not called :X i want to be called

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first line of any constructor that calls a super constructor must be the call to the super constructor.

Just move the call up to the first line:

```
public HotelReviewClass(String grade, String comment, String service, String local, String owner){
    super(grade, comment, owner);
    this.ratingService = service;
    this.ratingLocal = local;
}
```

Comment: that way the variables initialization are not called because go to "super"

or im wrong?

Comment: You are wrong. The call is made to the super constructor, and when it finished, execution continues in the subclass's constructor. This will work fine.